# how to select distinct values from a table when i need to select values having y if it has both y,n values and n values only if there is no y value

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table with data like

```
promo    flag 

ab21     y 
ab21     N  
bc22     N  
bc22     N  
CD23     Y  
CD23     Y 
ef24     N
ef24     y
```

i want distinct  promo ,flag from the table 
 but when a single promo has both Y,N flags i want only Y FLAG PROMO

*i.e* 
**expected output**

```
ab21 y
bc22 n
cd23 y
ef24 y
```

need help in building a simple query

like

```
select distinct promo,flag from table where ( your solution subquery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytical function like this:

```
Select promo, flag 
 from (Select promo, flag,  
       row_number() 
       over (partition by promo order by upper(flag) desc nulls last) as rn 
 From your_table) 
Where rn=1;
```

You can also use group by but it will restrict you to select any other columns from table in the result.

```
select promo, max(upper(flag)) from table
group by promo
```

Also, in group by query, it will be case insensitive so , I would recommend to use analytical function.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try, it is simpler way(from your test data):

```
select promo, max(lower(flag)) from table
group by promo
```

Comment: @RustamPulatov . . . I don't know if this is faster, but it is definitely simpler.  It might be faster -- Oracle has a good optimizer and has good implementations for aggregation.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Thank you. I think only "explain plan" says faster or not)